# AWS SES - Connect to boto set without exposing access keys in code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-ses

I am using python to send emails via an AWS Simple Email Service.

In attempt to have the best security possible I would like to 
make a boto SES connection without exposing my access keys inside the code.

Right now I am establishing a connection like this

```
ses = boto.ses.connect_to_region(
   'us-west-2',
    aws_access_key_id='<ACCESS_KEY>',
    aws_secret_access_key='<SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>'
)
```

> **Is there a way to do this without exposing my access keys inside the script?**

Comment: I would recommend you use boto3. You can see how to configure that [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html).

Comment: Are you executing the python code on a EC2 machine or a non-EC2 machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use environment variables you may retrieve in your Python code with `os.environ`.

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<YOUR REAL ACCESS KEY>
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<YOUR REAL SECRET KEY>
```

And in the Python code:

```
from os import environ as os_env

ses = boto.ses.connect_to_region(
   'us-west-2',
    aws_access_key_id=os_env['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    aws_secret_access_key=os_env['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']'
)
```

Answer (score 3):

To your EC2 instance attach an IAM role that has SES privileges, then you do not have to pass the credentials explicitly. Your script will get the credentials automatically from the metadata server.

See: [Easily Replace or Attach an IAM Role to an Existing EC2 Instance by Using the EC2 Console](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easily-replace-or-attach-an-iam-role-to-an-existing-ec2-instance-by-using-the-ec2-console/). Then your code will be like:

```
ses = boto.ses.connect_to_region('us-west-2')
```

Answer (score 2):

Preferred method of authentication is to use boto3's ability to read your AWS credential file.

Configure your AWS CLI using the `aws configure` command.

Then, in your script you can use the `Session` call to get the credentials:

`session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')`

Answer (score 2):

Two options are to set an environment variable named `ACCESS_KEY` and another named `SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, then in your code you would have:

```
import os
ses = boto.ses.connect_to_region(
'us-west-2',
aws_access_key_id=os.environ['ACCESS_KEY'],
aws_secret_access_key=os.environ['SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
)
```

or use a json file:

```
import json
path_to_json = 'your/path/here.json'

with open(path_to_json, 'r') as f:
    keys = json.load(f)

ses = boto.ses.connect_to_region(
'us-west-2',
aws_access_key_id=keys['ACCESS_KEY'],
aws_secret_access_key=keys['SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
)
```

the json file would contain:
`{'ACCESS_KEY':<ACCESS_KEY>, 'SECRET_ACCESS_KEY':<SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>}`